# How to use beautify for Javascript/React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I have installed `Beautify` to use it for my `ReactJS` code.
However, it apparently does not properly beautify the HTML format in the file.

For example, it turns this:

[image]

into this:
[image]

Among all the options, which option should I use to fix this ?

Comment: Use atom editor with prettier. https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but as you recommended Prettier works better for me.

Answer (score 5):

I used to have the same problem. Apparently beautify doesn't support JSX. 
I uninstalled and instead of it, I installed Prettier, it works great for me.

Hope I helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Just change language mode **javascript to javascript react** [temporary]

**VSCode Command:** (<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>)

**Or** Save file in **.jsx** format and change the **settings.json** file

```js
"files.associations": {
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Comment: This works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with this, there is also js-beautify's `-X` (`--e4x`) [option](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#options) which tells it to leave the XML content unchanged.