# Beautify makes JSX ugly please look at the below scenario. I have tried a solution from a previous question with no success

Tags: visual-studio-code, js-beautify

The beautify extension in VSCode gives the below output. please find the code below.

```
<div className="container">
            <span className="text-muted">
                 An amazing place to buy medicines.
            </span>
        </div>
```

When i attempt to beautify the above code i get the below output.

```
    < div className = "container" >
        <
        span className = "text-muted" >
        An amazing place to buy medicines. <
        /span> <
        /div>
```

Please suggest a solution? We are looking to implement standard coding practices in our project seems to have hit a roadblock here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740593/260229

```js
"files.associations": {
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Comment: yes. It did not work. Thanks for the suggestion.